# Firebase storage link Permission denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm getting the URL with `getDownloadURL` after i put the url inside a img tag but i get this error[image]

the rules of the storage are these:

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
    }
}
```

So everybody should be able to read, so i can't understand :(
somebody can help?

Comment: Hey @LucaSpezzano do mark the answer as correct, by clicking the V looking button next to the answer, it helps the future readers of the question and I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a missing permission. You need to check whether you have

`firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com`

as a member with a "Storage Admin" role. If you don't have one, then add it. That would fix the issue.

Here are the steps on how you can check and add permissions.

Go to [Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=testproject-200bd)
Navigate to Storage
Select your bucket then click show info panel.
You can also add the missing permission in the IAM & Admin if you want.

If it is not the problem then you are getting the error due to the some problem in the code, you may want to check it once more.